# Why the derivative formula $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$ fails when $n=1$ and $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The derivative formula $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$ is true for almost positive integers $n$ and all real numbers $x$, with the only exception that $n=1$ and $x=0$. May I know how to intuitively understand why the formula fails in this special case?

Comment: Because $0^0$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang, I understand $0^0$ is undefined. But it seems unnatural to me that the formula fails only at this particular case.

Comment: Actually $0^0=1$ so there is no exception.

Comment: @Zuriel It's not undefined, it is indeterminate. That means that it could have a value, but it is impossible to determine the way you are looking at it.

Comment: @bof In this case, yes, but it's indeterminate generally.

Comment: If you examine the proof of the formula, you will see that you get the limit of $x/x$ as $x\to0$ which is $1$ despite $0/0$ being an "ideterminate form".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume $n$ to be a positive integer and consider the ratio $$\frac{(x+h) ^n-x^n} {h} $$ From binomial theorem we have $$(x+h) ^n=x^n+nx^{n-1}h+\dots$$ if we put $n=1$ we just have $$x+h=x+h$$ and not $$x+h=x+1\cdot x^{0}\cdot h$$ In such situations one treats $x^0=1$ irrespective of the value of $x$. Same is the case with formula $$\frac{a^n-b^n} {a-b} =a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots +ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$$ This also applies to the first term of a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$. The first term is just $a_0$ and it is written as $a_0x^0$ to simplify notation.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not $0^0$ is defined, you can always think of such problem in terms of *limit*. Assume that $n=1$. What happens when $x\neq0$? It yields $1$, i.e., $nx^{n-1} = 1$. Thus

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to0} nx^{n-1} = 1.
\end{equation}

This way of see things have the following advantages.

1. It does not depend on an arbitrary definition. (Indeed, all definitions are made for some reasons.)
2. Even though some definition addresses your problem, examining it in this ways gives you better insight!

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Be careful with this. Derivatives need not be continuous.

Comment: You're right. But we know that the derivatives of polynomial (an analytic function) is continues. (But thx for pointing that out.)

Comment: I don't think this clearly answers the question. It should explain why the derivative can be computed by a limit using its definition but that plugging into the formula gives the indeterminate form.

Comment: @Jam Thanks for the great point, Jam! You're right. Probably that's what I should've done. But that's not what I was trying to do, i.e., the purpose was not the perfect proof or reasoning. Rather, handwavy way (but the conclusion is correct), which helps get insight better. Zuriel wanted intuitive answer, anyway. :)